# git как начать заново

Tags: git

У меня есть папка в java проектом, ранее пыталась ее залить на github, но ничего не вышло. Создала новый репозиторий на github, и пробую залить все сначала, но папка уже настроена на старый репозиторий. Команда git add . не добавляет ничего,  git push пытается залить в старое место. Подскажите как все очистить и начать и нуля?

Comment: Удалить папку .git в корне проекта можно для начала.

Comment: А можете уточнить, как пытались и что именно не вышло? Какие сообщения об ошибках были? Я думаю, что вам стоит разобраться в том, что не получилось. А вообще, как я понял, вам надо удалить папку `.git` из проекта, а потом выполнить команду `git init` повторно. Возможно, вы не указывали ветку при push'е? Попробуйте так: `git push origin master`

Comment: папки .git в корне почему то нет, а ошибки какие были не могу сказать это было давно - полгода назад, уже не помню.

Comment: Папка .git обязательно есть, просто она скрытая

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git remote set-url origin (и тут url вашего нового репозитория на гитхабе)
git push
```

Если `git push` не проходит - в данном случае допустимо сделать `git push -f`

Comment: git push -f # принудительно обновит из локального. Работая в команде над проектом этого делать не рекомендуется.

Comment: @VyacheslavMischenko вы вопрос-то читали? Задача-то была залить существующий код в новый, **свежесозданный** репозиторий на гитхабе!